# how to display in-app purchase in my app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm wondering how to display my in-app purchase in my app. I am building a magazine and want to have a list of mags in my app. When someone purchases the mag it then promps for the in-app purchase, which I have gotten through all that, but then what I don't understand is, how does it display the downloaded in-app purchase from that point, and how do I link to the downloaded mag from my main app once it is downloaded?

Comment: So, you want to have an app, that allows you to purchase another app?  Not show the content in your app?

Comment: have you read the relevant documentation already?

Comment: Yes I want to show the content in my app, but the additional content is not bundled with the app.... and I have found no documentation explaining this. If you could point me somewhere that would be great.